# How can I declare a variable as an element of a constant array?

Tags: java, arrays

I apologize for the poorly worded title but I couldn't think of a better way to phrase it. Here is my code (ignoring class and main method and other boilerplate):

```
int i = 2;
int j = {9,88,777,6666}[i];
```

I would expect j to be 777, but instead it refuses to compile. For reference, here is another snipper that I think should be basically equivilant, and does in fact work.

```
int i = 2;
int[] arr ={9,88,777,6666};
int j = arr[i];
```

Is there a way to do this on two lines like my first non-working example?

(I am aware this would almost never be a good idea, but I am doing something similar to codegolf and it seems like this should be possible somehow.)

Comment: This seems like an XY problem. What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: What do you mean XY problem? I am trying to do what the second snippet does in three lines, in two. The first snippet is what I wrote in trying to accomplish this, but it does not work.

Comment: [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) or [What is an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). It basically means that there is a problem with the chosen solution rather than the problem inherent in the actual task.

Comment: @PaulRooney I thought stackoverflow encouraged/required askers to post what they had already tried? Anyways, shmosel has solved it already.

Comment: @Riley I'm not saying you have an XY problem. I'm just defining it. Its absolutely fine to present with whatever problem you have.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since it's not a simple declaration and assignment, you would have to use the `new` syntax:

```
int j = new int[] {9,88,777,6666}[i];
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much! I'll accept the answer as soon as stackoverflow lets me.